Can't create, write and copy-paste file after mount SD card
I plug the SD card into the Ubuntu Laptop, it work.
I use command to unmount:
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p1

Then, I use command to mount:
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/ndp

After mount, I can't create new folder, cut/copy-paste or write file in SD card. I use Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, and I try on every format of SD card

What is the format of SD card?  is Ubuntu desktop or server? Please edit your question and add those info, not in comments.

Have you checked the write-protect slide switch isn’t in the read-only position on your sd card?

It seems like you are having some sort of permissions issue with the SD card once you mount it that way. If you are able to, check the read/write permissions of the SD card after you mount it. If it mounts automatically or you are using a file browser to mount it then the user performing the action is your user and will give it access to read and write to the SD card. When you use 'sudo' the user mounting the card is root and my not give your user permission to read or write.

Thank everyone, I solved this problem by adding uid to mount command:
sudo mount -o uid=ndp /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/ndp
or
sudo mount -o uid=1000 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/ndp
In order to get uid, use command:
id
